# Correct practice for iAd integration?

Tags: iphone, sdk, implementation, iad, ads

I've recently been implementing the iAd framework into my app and although it all works fine and it displays the test ads as it should, I was just wondering whether or not the method of implementation I've been using is the best practice as I've seen several people do this in different ways and in my personal opinion - unnecessarily complex.

Currently I just have an `adbannerview` as an outlet and then using the following code I load it or hide it depending on whether the ad is fulfilled, as Apple require.

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    adView.hidden = FALSE;
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    adView.hidden = TRUE;
}
```

I know it's nothing fancy in terms of animation but from what I've read of the 'interface guidelines' there's no need to animate the ads as they appear or disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need to do anything more when presenting an ADBannerView. Of course, as you said, animating it is fancier, but there is no problem on presenting it as you do.

If you want to present it animated on future versions of your app, [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app) you can find a great tutorial.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, I did find that tutorial when I was looking round. I may take a look into it if I get the time, just wanted to confirm that it was like this, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Looks fine to me. I am wondering why you are hiding the banner ad when you fail to get an ad. Generally you don't want to do things like that as it would encourage people to avoid getting ads (turning on airplane mode just when using your app, etc.)

Comment: He hides the banner because it is a requirement by Apple: _"If an error occurs, the banner view calls the delegate’s `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: method`. When this happens, your application must hide the banner view."_ http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html

Comment: As he said above that's why I did it. I guess people could turn of the internet but to tell you the truth its at their inconvenience as they'd have to keep turning it on and off. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So the reason I made that suggestion is because I use AdWhirl to present iAds and Admob ads and upon any sort of error I don't deliberately hide anything and it displays a blank white view. I prefer this sort of behavior rather than allow the user to get away with avoiding seeing the ad altogether. At the very least if they try circumventing your ads, they still lose the screen real-estate.